# Overwrite local files with files from master branch

Tags: git, github, fetch, branch

I started a project and pushed it into a github repo. Next, I wanted to add another feature, and I created a new branch (feature_branch). I started adding some code, but after running into a bunch of problems, I now would like to just overwrite my local files with the code I have in the master branch.

I tried:

`git checkout master` (to go back into the master branch)

`git fetch --all` hoping this would overwrite everything (I found this on https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/override-local-files-with-git-pull/13216)

At this point, I am getting the error

`fatal: 'feature_branch' does not appear to be a git repository`

`git branch -a` is showing me the following:

```
*master
remotes/origin/feature_branch
remotes/origin/master
```

I am a bit confused now. Sorry, I am kind of new to git, so far I've only really used to to commit "finished" projects or after adding new stuff, I never really tried to go back to an older version.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What you describe is a bit confusing, since `git fetch` has no business messing with your local branches, it only affects remote-tracking ones (which are also part of your local repo, but are not *your* branches). Even with `--all` which, in case you have multiple remotes, makes it that you fetch from all.

Comment: RomainValeri, like I said I came across this on that website (see link above). I also found out I can't fork my own repo, so I guess my question is, what git command do I use to overwrite my local files with my own git repo? :)

Comment: Oh, I see. But did you also do the `reset --hard`? Because *that* would definitely get rid of things.

Comment: RomainValeri, I haven't committed any of the recent changes. All that only exists locally. I will try the `reset --hard` now. Question though, you said it seems like my only branch is `master` or the branch creation failed, the how come I can see the `feature_branch` when I say `git branch -a`?

Answer (score 0):

**Why is your branch gone?**

Either you somehow deleted your feature-branch, or you maybe didn't notice that your branch creation failed for some reason*, but in any case since your code still has your recent modifications and the only local branch is master, it seems that the commits of your recent work were done on master unbeknownst to you.

* now [thanks to torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54916725/1057485) we know what happened, but the solution stays the same

**How to fix it?**

I'd say just go for `git stash`.

If you do, anything not committed yet will be put in a temporary commit on a special branch called `stash`, ready to pop out with `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` (or never be called again, for that matter, like you seem to want here).

The advantage it has over doing `git reset --hard` is that you *might* want, in a few days (or weeks?), to remember how things were in that failed branch, what you tried, and if so, having this content saved somewhere will be precious.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
git fetch --all
```

means *fetch from all **remotes***, not "fetch all branches".  Fetch already fetches all branches, but from just one remote (unless told otherwise).

The error message you are seeing means that one of your *remotes* is bogus.  You have a remote named `feature_branch`, along with the usual remote named `origin`.  The `fetch --all` tries to fetch from `origin`, which presumably succeeds, and also from the remote named `feature_branch`.  The URL attached to the remote named `feature_branch` is probably wrong and the fetch fails and you get the error you see.

Note that a remote is just a short string—of your choice—that stores a URL and provides the front part for remote-tracking names.  Hence the short string `origin` stores the URL for another Git, and also provides the `origin/` part of `origin/master` and so on.  You can create and delete remotes at will, using `git remote add` and `git remote remove`.  You can rename an existing remote with `git remote rename`.

Clean up the bogus remote and resume with the normal process of fiddling with branches.

Comment: Hmm... so kattapillar would have mistakenly declared a new remote instead of a branch? Seems clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the old branch, then delete the branch using `git branch -D branchName`.

Then, checkout to master `git checkout master`.

Then get the latest pull from master `git pull origin master`.

And then create the branch again `git checkout -b branchName`.

In this way you will have master branch data in your new branch,

I hope that helps!